# How to animate Text gradient using CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations, linear-gradients

i am using this CSS3 text shine gradient animation on my website (http://marekcmarko.xyz), but it keeps blinking if u scroll over the site and stop on headings where it's applied:

```
.textShineBlack {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 20%, #bada55 30%, #bada44 70%, #000 80%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
text-fill-color: transparent;
background-size: 200% auto;
animation: textShine 7s ease-in-out infinite;


@keyframes textShine {
to {
    background-position: 200%;
}
```

Does any1 know what should i do to get rid of that blinking ?  I have no idea...I can't make screenshot of this - dunno if its even possible.

Comment: How many instances of that are on the page? It seems that either that is putting a lot of weight on the browser's rendering engine, or there's a memory leak in your carousel - every time the slides change, the text animation freezes until the slide change completes. This article might give you some insight into how to smooth things out: https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108

Comment: I used it 7 times + slides = 11 classes. Well i removed it from flexslider slides, but it did not help, since i still see blocks of black and green when i quickly scroll up n down. I will try to disable slider completely if that helps and also read what u ve sent me. Thx

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you made the animation to infinite so when it will end it will restart immediately for the initial state. To avoid this you can add `alternate` to the animation:

```css
.textShineBlack {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 20%, #bada55 30%, #bada44 70%, #000 80%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  animation: textShine 7s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes textShine {
  to {
    background-position: 200%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="textShineBlack">SOME text</h1>
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, i used it with alternate but it keeps blinking. Well  when i scroll quickly up n down between headings "Schopnosti & Vlastnosti"  and "O mne". i

Comment: I've tried to restart firefox... well.. it keeps blinking, but somehow differently

Comment: @MarekCmarko Strange, am debugging to see what is happening ... but I think it's beause you are using a lot of animation and complex stuff on the site, so it get laggy

Comment: So far i've never thought it could be complex. When i take a look at real websites , though, built by frameworks, or WP themes i consider them to be complex, not that poor code i have.  I was just thinking it would be caused by javascript i wrote (and included)